# Jquery ajax to Express not able to catch data json data

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, body-parser

When i send Ajax request to expresss i catch the json data using req.body.email
The output in the console gives me undefined....please Help...

Client Side

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/getRandomPass',
          dataType: "json",

          data:{'emailId':'sampleemailiD@gmail.com'},
          type: 'POST',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            console.log("cleint recieved data",data);
           // this.setState({data: data});
          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
           console.log(xhr,status,err);
          }.bind(this)
    })
```

Server Side

```
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.post('/getRandomPass', function(req, res) {
       console.log("req",req.body.emailId);
        });
```

Comment: Do you set a response content-type?

Comment: Do you mean that `console.log("on success",data);` prints the html content?

Comment: @DustinToothless: I did set the content type to text like  res.set('Content-Type','text')

Answer (score 0):

Use $.getJSON to use Json strucutre. Check th link
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
$.getJSON("/getRandomPass", function( data ) {
        console.log("on success",data);
       });
```

Comment: Still gets html

Answer (score 0):

You should either use:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.send(text)
```

or:

```
res.end(text)
```

Comment: i have used both individually to test the things but none works

Comment: Then there must be some other problem in another part of your code.

Comment: can you please come on TeamViewer or skype and loop at my code